# Convex core and geometric finiteness of negatively curved manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading a paper on hyperbolic geometry where they are using the concept of "convex core" in the context of "geometric finiteness". Roughly, this means (from Definition F4 of a [paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1243787) of Bowditch) the following. Let $M^n$ be a negatively curved manifold, which is obtained as a quotient $X/\Gamma$, where $X$ is a pinched Hadamard manifold and $\Gamma \subseteq \text{Isom }X$ is discrete. Then the convex core of $M$ is defined as $C(M) := H/\Gamma$, where $H$ is the closed convex hull of the limit set of $\Gamma$.

Now, consider the "thick-thin" decomposition of $M$ as $M = M_{\text{thick}} \sqcup M_{\text{thin}}$. As mentioned by Bowditch (immediately following the definition), the intersection $C(M) \cap M_{\text{thick}}$ is compact. My question is, are the following statements correct?

1. The complement of $C(M) \cap M_{\text{thick}}$ is a disjoint union of cusps and funnels, each of  which is a  warped product of the form $N^{n - 1} \times [1, \infty)$, having finite and infinite volumes respectively. "Most part" of each cusp (funnel) is inside $M_{\text{thin}}$ ($M_{\text{thick}}$ respectively). However, the cusps are contained inside the convex core, while the funnels are not.
2. The fundamental group of each cusp and each funnel is amenable.
3. The group $\Gamma$ must have parabolic elements for cusps, and loxodromic elements for funnels.

I have put together an attempt to understand the concepts around geometric finiteness in my own way. If some statements are wrong, please excuse me and please point them out. I am unable to find a nice enough reference which has all these in one place, so that a novice like me can understand. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to assume $M$ has finite volume to be more specific about the cusps, which are noncompact and not contained in the convex core (which is compact). The cusps are basically complementary to the convex core. Have you reviewed Thurston's Three Dimensional Topology book? Or review the example of modular surface $X=\bf{H}^2 / PGL(\bf{Z}^2)$ in detail, which motivates the whole idea of the structure of cusps.

Comment: Did you read [Bowditch, B. H. Geometrical finiteness with variable negative curvature.
Duke Math. J. 77 (1995), no. 1, 229–274]?  Some of your questions are addressed there. The paper of Bowditch you refer to studies parabolic subgroups, not geometric finiteness. Generally, geometric finiteness in the negatively pinched case is very much like the hyperbolic case except that you have to replace abelian by nilpotent for parabolic subgroups. Funnels can certainly have non-amenable fundamental group, e.g. if $\Gamma$ is Fuchsian the fundamental group of the funnel is the $\Gamma$.

Comment: Here are some details from the Duke paper of Bowditch, as mentioned by @IgorBelegradek above. A discrete group of isometries of $X$ is called elementary if it is either (a) parabolic: fixes a point at infinity, and horospheres around that point, but no other point in the compactification, (b) elliptic: fixes a point inside $X$, but nothing else. It can be proved that such groups are in fact finite, and (c) loxodromic: fixes a geodesic.

Comment: Further, discrete virtually nilpotent groups of isometries are one of the above. Since you have linked the paper on discrete parabolic groups (probably you intended to link the one on geometric finiteness instead), let me add that a parabolic group of isometries is finitely generated, virtually nilpotent and contains parabolic elements. Again, the Duke paper of Bowditch that has been mentioned above.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Do you happen to have a reference for how the metric looks in the cusps and funnels? In dimension 2, they are given by a Fermi type metric with the "radial" component giving the distance from the geodesic at the "join". Is there an analogous description in higher dimensions?

Comment: @SMS: are you asking about constant or variable pinched negative curvature? In variable curvature any small local perturbation will keep the curvature pinched negative, so there cannot be any explicit form of the metric. One could still work out examples, see e.g. section 10 of  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0402268. In constant negative curvature every cusp is a warped product $dr^2+e^r g_F$ where $g_F$ is a flat metric on the cusp cross-section. Not sure how you define a funnel, and what you expect of the metric there; what is funnel's "cross-section"?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thanks. Yes, let's talk about the constant curvature case, and then one can use comparison theorems for the pinched curvature. I was thinking of a funnel pretty much along the lines of the OP: for example, take a convex cocompact hyperbolic manifold, and consider the ends which are outside the convex core and have infinite volume. But now I am confused whether there is a "cross-section".

Comment: @SMS: many people studied metrics on the boundary of the compact convex core, but I don't know much about that. Let me just say that taking an $r$-neighborhood $C_r$ of the convex core, which is $C^1$, and issuing geodesics orthogonal to $\partial C_r$ you get a geometric picture of each funnel.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek But then, one gets a complete description, right? Topologically the funnel is $[0, \infty) \times \partial C_r$, and the metric in the funnel is given by the warped metric $dt^2 + \sinh ^2t \;dg_{\partial C_r}^2$? Here $t$ denotes the parameter along the geodesics orthogonal to $\partial C_r$, and the $\sinh\; t$ term comes from the variation of Jacobi fields. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SMS First, we don't get $\sinh$ because $\sinh 0=0$ which would force the funnel to be a point at $\partial C_r$.  In the Fuchsian we get $\cosh$ but I see no reason why we should always get $\cosh$. Also we don't know the metric on $\partial C_r$. When $r\to 0$ the metric approaches the path metric on the (nonsmooth)  boundary of the convex core which has been extensively studied, so there is some information hidden there but it is complicated.